# Auto focus does not work on every Android phone

Tags: android, android-camera

Auto focus does not work on every Android phone. I am using the code `Camera.AutoFocusCallback()`

Answer (score 0):

Not all devices need to support auto-focus (according to the [manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.AutoFocusCallback.html)). If you need it - do not install the app on devices without it.

> Devices that do not support auto-focus will receive a "fake" callback
>   to this interface. If your application needs auto-focus and should not
>   be installed on devices without auto-focus, you must declare that your
>   app uses the android.hardware.camera.autofocus feature, in the
>    manifest element.